# I want to embed an ebook reader on my webpage

Tags: html, embed, reader

My friend wanted me to upload a part of his book to a website for people to test and see if they want the full book or not. What I want to know is if you guys know and ebook programs you can embed to a website or if I simply will need to program a very simple one in HTML myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
you can use the [BiB/i](http://bibi.epub.link/), go [here](http://the-digital-reader.com/2014/11/13/embed-ebook-website/) to see a demo.